# highchart treemap in R with more then 2 drilldowns makes a incorrectly nested map

Tags: javascript, r, highcharts, treemap

I'm creating a highchart treemap in R with three drilldown levels. I noticed that with more than 2 levels, the map comes out weird, with the entire map squeezed into one of the outermost parents while the other parents are empty, like this:

[image]

here is my code:

```
#set up
library(treemap)
library(highcharter)
set.seed(12345)

level1 <- letters[1:3]
level2 <- as.character(1:2)
level3 <- c("%", "*")

df <- expand.grid(level1, level2, level3)

df$size <- sample(20, nrow(df), replace=T)
df$color <- sample(20, nrow(df), replace=T)


tm <- treemap(df, index = c("Var1", "Var2", "Var3"),
              vSize = "size", vColor = "color",
              type = "value")

hc_tm <- highchart(height = 800) %>% 
  hc_add_series_treemap(tm, allowDrillToNode = TRUE,
                       layoutAlgorithm = "squarified",
                       name = "tmdata")
hc_tm
```

What am I missing here? Thanks for your help.

Comment: There a lot of issues, like @molle said, in the `hc_add_series_treemap` function. As you can see only level2 treemaps work. In fact I have to check why this function can't generalize to more levels. I don't have timelines but I will try to fix this in the next release of highcharter (1 or 2 month I guess).

Comment: Thanks! I can use the workaround until then.

Comment: hey @jbkunst, have you guys had a new release yet?

Comment: Hi @chungkim271, not yet. I've just released 0.5.0 but dont affect the treemaps. You can follow the issues here https://github.com/jbkunst/highcharter/issues/110

Answer (score 1):

This is an open issue https://github.com/jbkunst/highcharter/issues/117

The workaround in the answer did the job for now